# c++ inheritance and class members

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, initialization

I have a base class, a class derived from that base class, and another class derived from the derived class. My problem comes from using a constructor to determine how to construct the next class.

here is a simplified version of the issue I am having while using inheritance. I am new to c++.

The Base class:

```
class Grandfather
{
    public:
        Grandfather(int A, int B, int C) : a(A), b(B), c(C)
        {}

        virtual ~Grandfather();
        virtual int getA();
        virtual int getB();
        virtual int getC();

    private:
       int a,b,c;

};
```

The derived Father class:

```
class Father : public Grandfather
{
    public:
        Father(int d);
        virtual ~Father();
    private:
        int c; // i know this at compile time. How to define?

};
```

where in Father.cpp, the constructor is defined like:

```
Father::Father(int d){
    int a,b; //Father takes a parameter that then determines what a and b are

    switch(d){
       case 1:
          a=2;
          b=5
       case 2:
          a=6;
          b=9;
       default:
          a=10;
          b=2;
    }


   Grandfather(a,b,c); // where c is a known constant for this class
}
```

And the derived, derived Child class:

```
class Child : public Father
{
    public:
        Child() : Father(int d) // d is a known constant for this class
        {}
        virtual ~Child();
    private:
        int d; // how do i define d, if it is known at compile time?

};
```

So, `Child` has a known integer value at compile time. When a `Child` object is created, it automatically calls the `Father` constructor with its variable. The `Father(in d)` constructor looks at this variable that's been passed from the `Child`, does a quick operation, and then calls the GrandFather constructor with its own already known `int c`, and two more `int a,b` which were created based on the `int d` that was given. This obviously doesn't work, because the default `Grandfather()` constructor is automatically called

Comment: `enum { d = X };` to answer your question in the code-comments.

Comment: Rather a template parameter, optionally `static constexpr int` member. If OP wants to initialize it with argument passed to the constructor, too bad, only `const int`.

Comment: Fix the typos in `Child`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This obviously doesn't work, because the default Grandfather() constructor is automatically called

Good catch, and `Grandfather(a,b,c);` creates a separate temporary instance.

What you could do:

```
Father::Father(int d) :
Grandfather(determine_a(d), determine_b(d), c) // c is static constexpr
{
}
```

It might be two functions, or you could refactor it using `std::array` and one `determine_ab` function. It's your choice.

Comment: Nice, could these determine functions be members of Father class?

Comment: They could be non-member or `Father`'s `private` `static` or `Grandfather`'s `protected` `static` functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the `int c` value in the `Father` class, and you know it at compile time, just hardcode it in the call to `Grandfather`'s constructor. Same with the `int d` value in `Child` class. To determine the value of `A` and `B` before calling `Grandfather`'s constructor, I think LogicStuff has the correct and most pretty answer. I wrote a short example to you, I have shorted the orginal code, and just used the most relevant part of TS's code. Feel free to add the rest.

```
class Grandfather
{
        public:
                Grandfather ( int A, int B, int C ) : a ( A ), b ( B ), c ( C ) { }
        private:
                int a, b, c;
};

class Father : public Grandfather
{
        public:
                Father ( const int d ) : Grandfather ( determine_a ( d ), determine_b ( d ), 4 ) { }
                int determine_a ( const int );
                int determine_b ( const int );
};

class Child : public Father
{
        public:
                Child ( ) : Father ( 3 ) { }
};

int Father::determine_a ( const int d )
{
        if      ( d == 1 )      { return 2; }
        else if ( d == 2 )      { return 6; }
        else                    { return 10; }
}

int Father::determine_b ( const int d )
{
        if      ( d == 1 )      { return 5; }
        else if ( d == 2 )      { return 9; }
        else                    { return 2; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite. Also, the way you formatted those if statements looks pretty! Lets say, instead of an int being known at compile time, we have an object that is known at compile time. Would I be able to hard code the instantiation of the object in Grandfather's constructor without error?

Comment: It has been six months since last time i wrote C++, so I'm a little bit rusty. But I have corrected my mistakes in the example over. I'm not quite sure what you are asking about, but you cannot hardcode a instance of a object. You need the address of the object, and you don't know the address of the object when you are writing the code.